# How to dispose components of a form

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-2010

I'm dynamically creating components in a form in `Show` event. I need to distroy all components on Close event because next time OnShow event it should create components again. Here number of components are changed according to a number of data rows. I'm using

```
this->DestroyComponents();  
this->Close();
```

but when next time i call it either shows access violation or component already exists message 'cause it did not dispose components well at all.

How to correctly dispose form and it's components?

Comment: That frees the TForm itself

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the components you create, such as in a TList or TObjectList, and then loop through that when needed, calling `delete` on each component.

Comment: I am creating one more instance of a form and now it's ok!